# Attempting to Add a Column to the Folder Content Type Leads to "The content type "Folder" is sealed"

Tags: content-type

I want to add a column called "Relevance" to the Folder content type so that I can create views based off of it.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a sealed content type, you can only create a new content type and inherit from the sealed content type. You can inherit your custom content type from the Folder content type and add your column to this inherited content type.

This will not apply the changes to Folders that already exist.